# Why is one of my pineapple plants thriving and the other isn't?

Tags: plant-health, bromeliads

I planted two pineapples a few months ago. One is thriving and the other is barely surviving. Should I wait and see if it rebounds or just mulch it?

[image: healthy]
[image: not healthy]

Answer (score 2):

The second photo looks like a healthy plant that got eaten by an animal or run over with a lawn mower, not like a plant with a disease: purely mechanical damage of an otherwise healthy plant.

I'd just let it be and see if it has enough energy stored in the roots and enough remaining leaf mass to grow back - the worst thing to happen is that it doesn't.

If, on the other hand, you had some kind of infection (which you don't), I'd recommend removing it to protect the other plant.

Comment: That's what is puzzling me. The two plants are 6 feet apart. If it's an animal eating it, why one and not the other.

Comment: @MenachemEliyahu: wait for an other day. Also animal get full

Comment: @MenachemEliyahu the first one also has leaves that look nibbled at. Just less damage.

Comment: @Stephie both were from store bought pineapples and their leaves were clipped. The damaged one seemed to be growing, but not really producing new leaves. I noticed some time ago that the leaves seemed shorter than before.